# What is the matrix and directed graph corresponding to the relation $\{(1, 1), (2, 2), (3, 3), (4, 4), (4, 3), (4, 1), (3, 2), (3, 1)\}$?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, relations

> Let $R$ be a relation on set $A = \{1, 2, 3, 4\}$ defined by $$R = \{(1, 1), (2, 2), (3, 3), (4, 4), (4, 3), (4, 1), (3, 2), (3, 1)\}.$$  Find the matrix and directed graph of relation $R$.

Comment: It would be great if you told us what you have done so far !

Comment: Welcome to this site! This site is for posting your mathematical questions to get answers, not for posting your mathematical tasks (or assignments) to have someone do them for you. What have you tried? What is it that you don't understand? Once this is clear to you, you can ask a precise question (notice that your post does not contain a question, just an "order" to perform a task).

Answer (score 1):

Here's an illustrative example to get you going.  We take the relation $$R=\{\color{red}{(1,2)},\color{blue}{(2,1)},\color{green}{(3,3)}\}$$ on the set $A=\{1,2,3\}$.

For the matrix representation, we write $1$ in cell $(i,j)$ whenever $(i,j) \in R$, and $0$ otherwise.  In this case:
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & \color{red}{1} & 0 \\
\color{blue}{1} & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & \color{green}{1} \\
\end{bmatrix}.
$$

In the directed graph representation, we have the vertex set $A$ and draw an edge $i \rightarrow j$ whenever $(i,j) \in R$, and no edge otherwise.  In this example:

[image: directed graph representation]

Answer (score 0):

First and foremost, please note the corrections given by my colleagues. We discuss questions here...not just doing assignment for you.

A matrix of the form $C_{ij}$ below whose entries are either 0 or 1 is called the adjacency matrix of the directed graph of relation $R$.

$$B_{ij}=\begin{pmatrix}
 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ \hline
 1& - & - & - & - \\
 2& - & - & - & - \\
 3& - & - & - & - \\
 4& - & - & - & -
\end{pmatrix}$$

In order to obtain matrix $C_{ij}$, you only fill the missing entries of matrix $B_{ij}$ with 1 or 0 according as whether there is a relation between the elements in the horizontal and vertical components or not.

For example, because $(1,1),(2,2),(4,1)\in R$, we filled their corresponding entries with 1, and since $(2,1),(3,4)\notin R$, we filled the corresponding entries with 0.

$$C_{ij}=\begin{pmatrix}
 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
 1 & 0 & 1 & 1
\end{pmatrix}.$$

**Remarks**: The word directed simply tells you that edge (i,j) is not the same as edge (j,i) while for an undirected graph, edge (i,j) is the same as edge (j,i).